# showing shopping cart items for django?

Tags: python, django, cart

i use python 3.7 and django 2.2.3

i'm creating ac shopping cart system for my website and i  can't see my cart items in it. i use product.id in URL's Patterns, but it seems it not working. 
this is my website shopping cart and i want after clicking a add to cart button , it add to the cart and show me cart page.
i tried this by using product.id in url patterns and update_cart() view in views.py.

i use `"{% url 'update_cart' product.id %}"` for clicking 'ADD TO CART' in product page.
i use `"{% for item in cart.products_list.all %}"` for showing cart items in cart page.

views.py

```
def cart_view(request):
    cart=Cart.objects.all()[0]
    return render(request,'products/cart.html',{'cart':cart})

def update_cart(request,product_id):
    cart=Cart.objects.all()[0]
    try:
        product=Products.objects.get(id=product_id)
    except Products.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    if not product in cart.products_list.all():
        cart.products_list.add(product)
    else:
        cart.products_list.remove(product)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("cart")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/',views.create,name='create'),
    path('<int:product_id>/',views.detail,name='detail'),
    path('cart',views.cart_view,name='cart'),
    path('cart/update/<int:product_id>/',views.update_cart,name='update_cart')
```

models.py :

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    products_list=models.ManyToManyField(Products,null=True,blank=True)
    total=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
    isPaid=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def count_cart_items(self):
         return int(self.cart_items)

class Products(models.Model):
    category_id=models.ForeignKey(Products_Cat,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creator=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description=models.TextField()
    slug=models.SlugField()
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    isOff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

i want to see my cart works correctly and showing me the cart but i see no result with no error. Can Anyone Help ?

Comment: can anyone help ?

Comment: What do your URL patterns functions look like?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have unique urls, this two urls are same:

```
path('<int:product_id>/',views.detail,name='detail'),
path('<int:product_id>/',views.update_cart,name='update_cart')
```

so you need to change it,
and it would be better to create multiple urlpattern to categorize it
for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('cart/', views.cart_view, name='list_cart'),
    path('cart/create/', views.create, name='create_cart'),
    path('cart/detail/<int:product_id>/', views.detail, name='detail_cart'),
    path('cart/update/<int:product_id>/', views.update_cart, name='update_cart'),
]
```

Comment: hi   i changed this     "  path('<int:product_id>/',views.update_cart,name='update_cart') " to this     "  path('cart/update/<int:product_id>/',views.update_cart,name='update_cart')  " , but still not working